# Client functions vs MySQL functions

Tags: python, mysql, ruby, function, client

Upper-casing of a string can be done in two ways:

1. Using a MySQL function with `SELECT` statment, like `` SELECT UPPER(bio.`name`) FROM `bio` WHERE `id` = 1 ``
2. Using a Client function, like `"string".upcase` OR `"string".upper()` in **Ruby** and **Python** respectively, after fetching raw data from MySQL server database.

First one is done with **MySQL** Server, latter one is done with **Server-Side** language (which works as a client for MySQL).

So which is **the right approach**?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to dismiss the case in the condition during database match, or do you want to modify the result to dismiss the case?

Comment: @sawa I didn't get it. Comment not clear.

Comment: I think there's no right or wrong approach, especially if the result is a single value. Maybe there will be a measurable difference if the result are a lot of rows, but I doubt it.

Comment: I personally prefer client functions, as they do not depend on chosen database. Good example is function MySQL'DATE' vs postgres 'date_part`.

Comment: @BroiSatse That's a very good point.